# How to make RPG Maker VX Ace stop crashing steam?

Tags: rpg-maker-vx

Every time I try to load RPG Maker VX Ace through Steam, it crashes Steam and prevents itself from loading. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? The last time I used it, I did put a lot of .mp3 files onto it, but that was the last thing I did (besides working on a game).

Comment: Is there an error log attached to the crash, or perhaps any relevant information to analyze?

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/app/220700/discussions/1/558747287803138633/ has a few answers, notably they Suggest to run both Steam and the RPG Maker client under Administrator, disabling steam-cloud, opting out of the beta if for some reason you entered it.  They Note a beta called Pre-Workshop that if out opt out of, may fix your crash.

Comment: @Shroeder there is no relevent information whats so ever. When I try to load it, it keeps loading until the game loading image appears (not the Steam one, but the one RPG Maker loads) and then Steam just shuts down and RPG Maker Vx Ace is unable to load.